# What is CLI/C++ exactly? How does it differ from 'normal' c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

Let me clarify what I mean by 'normal' C++ first- I'm currently reading Walter Savitch's "Problem Solving in C++". As far as I am aware this is not written specifically for Microsoft or Unix. So my question is, how does what I am learning in this book (which I am using for my universal knowledge-gaining of c++) differ from what I keep reading about CLI C++?

Is CLI C++ just what I would encounter if I used Visual C++? I'm totally confused.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

C++/CLI, (Also sometimes C++/CLR) refers to a language which is positioned somewhere in between native C++, and the .NET framework.

It's usually used for applications where you need to bridge some native code (pure C++) and managed code (Like VB, C#, F#, etc).

C++/CLI is a much different beast than regular C++ though. And when people say Visual C++, the meaning can vary depending on context. Sometimes they mean C++ with the common language runtime (CLR) layer enabled, other times they mean just plain C++. It's unfortunate that there's a lot of different terminology out there, and a lot of misnomers, but what can you do?

Comment: So if i just wished to use the standard C++, templates and boost i wouldnt need CLR? Why would I need to use CLR, if I wanted to use .NET libraries? Thanks

Comment: You would use CLR any time you plan on calling .NET libraries, or if you want your code to play nice with .NET code that's calling it. If your desire is to just write plain C++, don't even bother with C++/CLI. Both have their intended domains, but if you're writing pure C++ there's no need for CLR.

Comment: "*Also sometimes C++/CLR*" No -- the name of the language is C++/CLI; if it's ever called C++/CLR, it's a mistake by someone who doesn't know any better.

Answer (score 8):

C++ and C++/CLI differ greatly. C++/CLI is the managed .NET-version of C++, made by Microsoft to enable a layer from .NET to native code.

Answer (score 1):

c++/cli is the current version of Microsoft's Visual c++ brand of tools.  (There was a different design before c++/cli)

c++/cli is really two versions of c++ in one.  There is a highly standardized c++ compiler and also a version of c++ that runs on the CLI virtual machine.  Obviously standard c++ never runs on a VM so that determined the two in one approach to the language.

When using it you can mix unman aged and managed code together.  "Unmanaged" is code compiled just like standard c++.  "Managed" is code compiler to the CLI (.Net) virtually machine's bytecode.  Microsoft has extensive APIs for both managed and unmanaged code.  With the product you can access both APIs.

You can develop standard c++ apps with the language and tool, you just have to be careful not to used the non-standard extensions.  I suggest compiling in another compiler once in a while if you are in doubt.  The managed side is totally non standard and even the unmanaged side has tons of non standard extensions.

PS I'm no expert but I was curious and read about this last week.  I thought your question deserved an answer.  Good luck!

Comment: "c++/cli is the current version of Microsoft's Visual c++ brand of tools." This is a bit inaccurate/misleading. Visual Studio is the toolset. C++/CLI is one of the languages supported therein.

Comment: *"a version of c++ that runs on the CLI virtual machine"* - There is the CLR, which is a *virtual execution environment*. This is **not** a virtual machine. IL code is **always** compiled to native machine code before execution. *"Obviously standard c++ never runs on a VM"* - There's nothing obvious about that, and nothing in the C++ Language Specification mandates that C++ is required to compile to native machine instructions. C++ could very well be implemented to run in a VM, and still be called *"Standard C++"*.